# Installer for Windows 8.1 store app

Tags: deployment, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I have purchased the Windows sideloading key to deploy an LOB app without using
Windows Store. My clients are reluctant to use powershell to install the app.

Is there a way to automate the powershell installer to a much more user friendly
way? So I can give a one click installer to install the app on devices.

Using an MDM is very costly, devices can't be domain joined either, and I don't know any other way of doing it. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Try WiX Poweshell extension, https://github.com/flcdrg/PowerShellWixExtension and create standalone installer.